# Fatorial em python,

Tags: python, pycharm, fatorial

Gente, sou nova na area de programação, e fazendo exercicios me deparei com a seguinte questao:

Faça um programa que calcule o fatorial de um número inteiro fornecido pelo usuário. `Ex.: 5!=5.4.3.2.1=120`

Como utilizar o `pycharm` para resolver isso?

Comment: `f=lambda x :x if x<=2 else x*f(x-1)`

Answer (score 2):

Para o problema de fatorial é bem simples resolver usando uma função recursiva:

```
def fatorial(n):
    if n<=1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*fatorial(n-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Bom, existem várias maneiras de resolver seu problema. Duas maneiras bem simples são usando recursão e um simples loop:

```
def fat1(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return n*fat1(n-1)

def fat2(n):
    resultado = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        resultado *= i
    return resultado
```

Outra opção, em um estilo mais funcional:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def fat3(n):
    return reduce(mul, range(1, n+1), 1)
```